# MVC can not log on online

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm learning how to write simple websites with MVC 3. I have a little problem with loging on to my website. I created an account via ASP.Net Configuration site and there is no problem to log in unless I try to do this not on localhost. When I use log in form on my published online site, it takes a while and redirecting me to /shared/error. What did i wrong? Maybe I forgot about some libraries? I use default Account system, just this one which is created in new Web App project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you using for persistence on the server? the ASP.Net Configuration is creating a user account in a database.  If you don't explicitly specify a database, one is created for development purposes for you, but it is not copied to the server.

Also, there are some tables inserted into the database for you by the ASP.Net Configuration site for supporting users, roles, etc.  These tables would need to be created on your server. see [Creating the Membership Schema in SQL Server](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/creating-the-membership-schema-in-sql-server-cs)

If possible, you should consider MVC 4 instead of MVC 3, since the pre-built templates for it use [Simple Membership](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx) instead of the full featured ASP.net Membership providers. Simple Membership uses only a few tables, and the views and stored procedures have been removed.

Comment: Ok, I'm now manually converting my code to mvc 4 project. Could you recommend me any tutorial, which will teach me what tables should i create in my db and how should i rewrite default connection string to acces this one database without edditing default account models and controllers?

Comment: http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253806 The official documentation should help with adding the correct namespaces and upgrading the web.config